# What's the most practical way to render dynamic components in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and converting my old react application to a Next app to take advantage of SSR for SEO (among other nifty features Next provides). Currently my component setup is:

HomePage

- about(component)
- ... body components
- contact(component)

As I understand I cannot make fetch calls in the getServerSideProps function and I wish not to bloat my Homepage with a lot of code.

I'm leaning towards Incremental Static Regeneration as the homepage components do not need to be updated quickly. However if I understand correctly, I'll need to make a call by refreshing to update the stale data (a hassle I wish to avoid).

Can I make all my fetch calls in getServerSideProps and pass them to my components? And if so, is this bad practice/ solution to my problem?

Comment: What makes you think that it's bad practice?

Comment: @SeanW I'm trying to avoid rebuilding the app for every update

Comment: @evolutionxbox just checking to see if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this

Comment: @SeanW every 2-3 days

Comment: @SeanW I'm using a CMS

Comment: If you're looking for more efficient way to write your code I would recommend visiting https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have infrequent builds and low amount of pages you can use any of the three build types that Next.js offers.

If you use [Vercel's hosting](https://vercel.com/solutions/nextjs), it's really up to you as they handle the deployment. If you're not using them, it is likely not worth the effort to setup ISR or SSR at your current stage.

Here is the [Next.js recommendations](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) when fetching data. This page also contains a lot of setups with CMS's.

#### Static site generation (SSG)

SSG is probably the most basic of the solutions and is likely most similar to how a basic vanilla React app is deployed.

Since you have a few pages and infrequent builds this is a great solution (it's the one I'd use - but I primarily use AWS).  A SSG site will build in a 1-2 minutes and you can automate the process with something like GitHub Actions.  Here is a [easy to follow video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3h91EvRxuk) using SSG, GitHub Actions, and AWS.

#### Incremental static regeneration (ISR).

Slightly more involved setup but this approach would be faster rebuilds with the same benefits as SSG. Here is a [good article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/incremental-static-regeneration-nextjs/) on this approach.

#### Server-side Rendering (SSR)

Building a server-side app using `getServerSide` props is a perfectly viable solution.  This approach will also allow you to use all of Next's features like [Image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) that is currently not available on the other approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by next/image is not available on the other approaches? AFAIK none of Next.js‘s data fetching methods have any effect on next/image.

Comment: Ahh got it! Since you only mentioned next/image for `SSR` I assumed you meant it's not available for the other approaches like `SSG`.

Comment: Your assumptions were correct.  Currently, you cannot use next/image with an exported site (i.e., SSG) with the default loader. Next/image manipulates images in real-time on the server. There isn't a server to process the images after a site is exported – it's just static files.  However, you can make a custom loader/api endpoint outside of your static site or use a 3rd party service and tell next/image to use that loader. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image  here are some alternatives for a static site https://maxrohde.com/2021/07/25/next-js-11-images-with-static-export/

Comment: Sorry, I implied deployment to Vercel where you can both use SSG and SSR data fetching methods without any effect on next/image out of the box. But yes you are right, not using Vercel this requires extra effort.